# How to implements Iterable

Tags: java, foreach, iterator, iterable, implements

In my program, I write my own LinkedList class. And an instance, llist.

To use it in foreach loop as following, LinkedList needs to implement Iterable?

```
for(Node node : llist) {
    System.out.print(node.getData() + " ");
}
```

Here following is my LinkedList class. Please let me know how can I make it Iterable?

```
public class LinkedList implements Iterable {
    private Node head = null;
    private int length = 0;

    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }

    LinkedList (Node head) {
        this.head = head;
        this.length = 1;
    }

    LinkedList (LinkedList ll) {
        this.head = ll.getHead();
        this.length = ll.getLength();
    }

    public void appendToTail(int d) {
        ...
    }

    public void appendToTail(Node node) {
        ...
    }

    public void deleteOne(int d) {
        ...
    }

    public void deleteAll(int d){
        ...
    }

    public void display() {
        ...
    }

    public Node getHead() {
        return head;
    }
    public void setHead(Node head) {
        this.head = head;
    }
    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(this.length == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The JDK is open-source, and the source comes with it. Just look at the standard LinkedList implementation to have an example.

Comment: But first you'll want to read a basic tutorial on the general subject of how to implement interfaces. You can find a decent one [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html). You won't regret doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Implement the only method of the `Iterable` interface, [`iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator%28%29).

You will need to return an instance of [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) in this method.  Typically this is done by creating an inner class that implements `Iterator`, and implementing `iterator` by creating an instance of that inner class and returning it.

Comment: Could you please specify? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please specify what you'd like me to specify?

Comment: Could you please implement the iterator()?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with interface and implements. Thank you so much for your help!